# how to keep the foot on the ground?

Tags: animation, armature, inverse-kinematics

Is there a way to keep the foot joint not moving when the hip joint moving up? in blender?
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/08c33feeb4824c6aa523a677c177c89d.   hello
@moonboots

Comment: I can't see the controllers you're showing in your picture, could you please share the good file?

Comment: @moonboots I think it must using ik no other way

Comment: maybe but there is no controller in the file you share